# Contravariance and method signature?

Tags: c#, .net, covariance, contravariance

looking at this code

```
delegate void StringAction (string s);
class Test
{
static void Main()
{
    StringAction sa = new StringAction (ActOnObject);
    sa ("hello");
}
static void ActOnObject (object o)
{

   Console.WriteLine (o); // hello
 }
}
```

Is this code is working due to Contravariance ? ( MoreDeriverdRef    <==   LessDerivedRef )

**or because**

(*unrelated to contravariance*) - In c# I can execute a  method like `ActOnObject (object o)` with `ActOnObject ("lalala")`

Comment: Your second point is related to contravariance.

Comment: @Jodrell why ? you can execute dowork(myHorse) on  method that accept animal .....and im not talking about delegates ....just normal  methods

Comment: but thats because method calls are contravariant, we are just used to it. It makes polymorphism work.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This code works because, as Eric Lippert says in [this article](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/ericlippert/archive/2007/10/19/covariance-and-contravariance-in-c-part-three-member-group-conversion-variance.aspx):

> Method group to delegate conversions are contravariant in their
>   argument types.

The above is only true for reference types, but both `string` and `object` are reference types, so the requirements are satisfied.

This kind of variance has been supported since C# 2.0, you do not need the additional support introduced in version 4 to rely on it.

Comment: Technically, it works because of the second reason, but that's still a form of contravariance.

Comment: thats more like it  - the second reason. so there is nothing to do with contravariance ...? if this code was running with 2005 (fw2) would it still work ? ( i dont have to test)

Comment: Yes, it will work from C# 2.0 onwards. That's still contravariance though, only it does not need the new `in` keyword. I guess you can say this makes it implicit rather than explicit.

Comment: lol you're zigzag :-) c# 2 doesn't support cov. so why are you writing _That's still contravariance though_ ? Thanks ;-)

Comment: Well, the fact that you can implicitly convert an `Action<object>` into an `Action<string>` is a form of contravariance. The C# language supported a few kinds of covariance/contravariance before version 4 (even though covariance on arrays was arguably broken).

Comment: correct me if im wrong  - but if this code works on 2005 - then this has nothing to do with cov / contravariavnce.

Comment: You seem to believe that C# did not support covariance and contravariance *at all* before the introduction of `in` and `out` in version 4. This is not true, as the language already supported a subset of these features since version 2.

Comment: unrelated to my question : `public void doWork(object o){};    dowork("lala");` ... why this code is working ? this is because object  is larger than string. so it can accept it.  are u telling me still it has a connection to contravariance ?

Comment: and p.s. I was talking not if this code will work in fw 2 but in compiler of 2005 !

Comment: The example in your last comment works because `string` is implicitly convertible to `object`, but that's not the same thing as your previous examples (no method group conversion is taking place).

Answer (score 0):

Yes it is due to Contravariance.

> This means that you can assign to delegates not only methods that have
>   matching signatures, but also methods that return more derived types
>   (covariance) or that accept parameters that have less derived types
>   (contravariance) than that specified by the delegate type.

Taken from http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd233060(VS.100).aspx